# Perl: Handle multiple non-blocking sockets (server)

Tags: perl, sockets

I am developing a server as a kind of gateway/router that opens a dynamic number of inbound, non-blocking tcp ports/sockets. The number of sockets is dynamically read from a config file, therefore the sockets are stored in an array.

I re-used older code with only one inbound socket, that used IO::Select.

My new code creates an array of in_lists (IO::Select) with the corresponding socket.

My current problem is: 
After opening all sockets, only the last socket is connectible - all sockets before refuse the connection.

```
## Listen to a guest TCP connection
our @tcpin_sock;
our @in_list;

foreach my $host (@config::hostkeys) {
    # Create In-Port
    $tcpin_sock[$host] = create_in_socket($tcpin_sock[$host], $inport, 'tcp');
    $in_list[$host] = IO::Select->new($tcpin_sock[$host]);

}

while (1) {
    # Listen to incoming TCP guests
    foreach my $host (@config::hostkeys) {
        #print STDERR "Listen for guests for $host...\n";
        if (my @in_ready = $in_list[$host]->can_read(0.2)) {
            foreach my $guest (@in_ready) {
                if($guest == $tcpin_sock[$host]) {
                    my $new = $tcpin_sock[$host]->accept or die "ERROR: It seems that this port is already occupied: $! ($@)\n";
                    my $newremote = $new->peerhost();
                    print STDERR "New guest connection accepted from $newremote.\n";
                    $in_list[$host]->add($new);
                } else {
                    $guest->recv(my $guest_line, 1024);
                    print STDERR $guest_line;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that my handling of IO::Select is wrong, and that it does not support multiple lists?
What I need would be the handling of multiple sockets, but on every client connection, inside the client processing, I need to know to what port/socket the connection was created to.

Has someone an idea how to implement the IO::Select for that case?

Thank you!
Christian

Comment: You should have a single select with multiple handles, not one select per handle

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you handle the `if($guest == $tcpin_sock[$host]) {` when I have multiple open sockets?

Comment: Have you tried out the "example" at the bottom of the [`IO::Select`](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) documentation? An aside: although it has a bit of a learning curve and might be overkill in your case, I like [POE](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/TCP_Servers) and have written a few servers with it ([one example](https://bitbucket.org/haukex/hgpstools/src/HEAD/sermux/serialmuxserver.pl)).

Comment: A single listen socket, that the `IO::Select` example states, was and is working. I've managed to change the code to only have one IO::Select list, and now both sockets are connectable, but only the last opened port reacts to transfers. `POE` looks promising but unfortunately is not available pre-compiled in the Debian repo.

Comment: To continue my project, I'll now start a Perl instance for each port, having all processing for a port/socket on one place.

Comment: Look at `IO::Multiplex`, this simplifies a lot of things when you have enough with a single process managing all sockets.